# Изменение значения глобальной переменной

Tags: python, python-3.8

У меня есть глобальная переменная `a = 50` в файле `rating.py`

как мне добавить 1 к значению a из файла `ChangeRating.py`

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса
В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

`rating.py`

```
a = 50
```

`ChangeRating.py`

```
from rating import a
print(a) 
a += 1
print(a)
```

Вывод:

> `50`

> `51`